# Why canvas doesn't work with jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have made simple example of using canvas and then I saw that my code doesn't work when I use jQuery selector.

**Examples:**

[Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/cXXdP/4/)

```
    window.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillRect(10,50,100,200);
    };
```

[JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/46VKa/2/)

```
   window.onload = function() {
        var canvas = $('#myCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillRect(10,50,100,200);
    };
```

So I have no idea why it happened. Is there any limitations about it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check this updated version of your jQuery fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/46VKa/3/

The problem was:

`var canvas = $('#myCanvas')` gets you a jQuery extended object and not a native DOM element object that has member functions like getContext etc. For this, you need to get the canvas element using `var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0]`

*NOTE:* `var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');` is equivalent to `var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0]`

Comment: Using `$('#myCanvas')[0]` to get the native object did the trick for me (-: Thanks alot man.

Answer (score 12):

```
window.onload = function() {
     var canvas = $('#myCanvas');
     var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d'); // not canvas.getContext('2d')
            
     ctx.fillRect(10,50,100,200);
};
```

in your code you're using `canvas.getContext('2d');`, but it should be `canvas[0].getContext('2d');`.

Because `getContext('2d')` works on ***DOM element***, where `var canvas = $('#myCanvas');` return a ***`jQuery object`*** but node a ***DOM element***.

And to retrieve a ***DOM element*** *(here, canvas element)* from jQuery object you need to use `canvas[0]`.

---

In you JavaScript code you're using:

`document.getElementById('myCanvas');` which returns a DOM element. So,

`var canvas = $('#myCanvas');`

`canvas[0]` and `document.getElementById('myCanvas');` are same.

---

#### *You can also change the jQuery code like*:

```
 window.onload = function() {
     var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0]; // get the element here
     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            
     ctx.fillRect(10,50,100,200);
};
```

Comment: +1 so if I need to find elm inside canvas, I should use `$('canvas')[0].find('element')` will this work?

Answer (score 1):

This code...

```
var canvas = $('#myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Needs to be...

```
var canvas = $('#myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get function of jquery to retrieve canvas element.

```
var canvas = $('#myCanvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
```