# jQuery selectors hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider following html structure:

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="http://test">
      < cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="ge" style="width: 77px; height: 14px;">
        <canvas width="89" height="15" style="width: 89px; height: 15px; top: 0px; left: -2px;"> 
        </canvas>
          <cufontext>test</cufontext>
      </cufon>
    </a>
</div>
```

What would be the easiest way to select the `canvas` object via jQuery selector but in a full hierarchical manner?

eg. pseudo code. $("#test > a:first > .cufon cufon-canvas > canvas")

Comment: "in a full hierarchical manner" What do you mean? As i understand it: `$("#test > a:first > .cufon > canvas")`

Comment: You don't need to traverse the whole hierarchy if you have an ID to target.

Comment: I know but I specifically need to do it that way for research purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#test > a:first > .cufon.cufon-canvas > canvas")
```

You need to use `.cufon.cufon-canvas` to select two classes instead of `.cufon cufon-canvas`

Comment: I see, so cufon cufon-canvas are actually two classes

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 $('#test canvas')[0]
```

`$('#test canvas')` will get you a jQuery extended object and not a native DOM element object that has member functions like getContext etc [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11574071/1719752).

Answer (score 0):

You can select like below

```
$('#test').find('canvas');
```