# Can't get star Indicator to apply to more than one element

Tags: jquery, canvas

I am doing this site of mine where I want to use stars as indicator for my skills.
The total amount of stars is 5,
I used this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8j6kdf4o/) (It is modified a bit based on what I wanted to achieve) that I found in the question [How to draw a star by using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837158/how-to-draw-a-star-by-using-canvas-html5). Here is the code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=20></canvas>

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawStar(cx, cy, spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius,fill) {
    var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
    var x = cx;
    var y = cy;
    var step = Math.PI / spikes;

    ctx.strokeSyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
    for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
        x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
        y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y)
        rot += step

        x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
        y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y)
        rot += step
    }
    ctx.lineTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth=1;
    ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle=fill;
    ctx.fill();

}

drawStar(10, 11, 5, 10, 5,'skyblue');
drawStar(30, 11, 5, 10, 5,'green');
drawStar(50, 11, 5, 10, 5,'transparent');
drawStar(70, 11, 5, 10, 5,'navy');
drawStar(90, 11, 5, 10, 5,'aquamarine');
```

As you can see, it only applies only to one canvas element (you can use ID once). But I have like 10 skills with different settings. I used to have circles as indicators and classes like one, two, three. It worked like a charm for each canvas element.
But, alas, It doesnt work in this case. Do I have to manually type ID to the individual canvases to make these Star shaped indicators, or there is a better way?

Comment: Agree with @SatejS about font-awesome. However if you insist, you might make a id array and loop the array calling the drawing function.

Comment: Or even just unicode star characters with HTML entities, e.g. `&#9733;`

Comment: @SatejS Maybe cause he wants to use canvas and draw it.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is show a series of stars next to a skill to indicate your proficiency, e.g. for a person profile site, this is probably the sort of thing you want to use, for simplicity's sake if nothing else: https://jsfiddle.net/pty065e4/ . Not to say that what you're working with here isn't a good exercise to learn the canvas, and if it's fun, then hey, go for it!

Comment: try using class selector like `$(".canvas")[i]` where i will range upto length of elements with `canvas` class. Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574038/why-canvas-doesnt-work-with-jquery-selector

Comment: @Rob, Absolutely!He/she is free to use whichever method.However, for the given use case, font-awesome and the unicode option suggested by kenbellows seemed much simpler.Also, maybe op isn't aware of these two alternatives, thus the comment.Sorry if it came across as rude.

Comment: @Rob: its ok...I only asked for suggestions to solve the problem, not ultimate answer or bust. I really appritiate your suggestion. I will try your suggestion as well.
-kenbellows: I guess I have to learn more, coz it never came into my mind to use unicode characters to represent starshapes